# CodeChef- Chef and Strange Formula

Tags: c, programming-challenge, mathematics, time-limit-exceeded

> For positive integer x let define function F(x) = 1 * (1! + x) + 2 * (2! + x) + .. + x * (x! + x).
>
> "k!" means factorial: k! = 1 * 2 * .. * k
>
> Chef wants to calculate F(p1) + F(p2) + ... + F(pn).
>
> As answer could be large, help him, calculate value modulo m.

**Input**

> First line contains two integers n and m.
> Next line contains n space separated integers pi.

**Output**

> Output a single line containing one integer --- calculated value modulo m.

**Constraints**

```
1 ≤ n ≤ 10^5
1 ≤ pi ≤ 10^18
1 ≤ m ≤ 10^7
```

**Subtasks**

```
Subtask #1: 1 ≤ pi ≤ 6 (10 points)
Subtask #2: 1 ≤ pi ≤ 7 * 10^3 (25 points)
Subtask #3: m - prime number (25 points)
Subtask #4: original constraints (40 points)
```

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 10000000 

long long int factorial(long long int n)
{
    long long int i,fact=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        fact=((fact%M)*(i%M))%M;
    return fact;
}
long long int func(long long int n)
{
    long long int a=((n%M)*(n%M)*((n+1)%M))%M/2;
    long long int sum=(a+factorial(n+1)-1)%M;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    long long int n,m;
    scanf("%lld%lld",&n,&m);
    long long int i,p[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&p[i]);
    }
    long long int sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+=func(p[i]);
    }
    printf("%lld\n",sum%m);
    return 0;
}
```

My code exceeds time limit on subtasks 2,3 and 4. How do I improve efficiency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As youself noted `F(x)` can be reduced to:

```
x*x*(x+1)/2 + (x+1)! - 1
```

As @Daniel Sokolov pointed, you don't need to calculate full factorial for each `p[i]`. If `p` is a sorted array, you can use previously calculated factorial in the current `(x+1)!` calculation.

Furthermore it would be better to get modulo after **each** arithmetic operation. This ensure that the current result after each operation will always `< m*m < 10^14`.

So the code might look like this:

```
/**
 *  @param m modulo
 *  @param n number of integers
 *  @param p sorted array of integers
 *  @return sum of F(pn) series modulo m
*/
function sum(unsigned long m, unsigned n, unsigned long long int *p) {
    unsigned long long int
        x, // current element of p array
        x0 = 1, // previous element of p array
        a, // sum of arithmetic progression
        fac = 1, // factorial of (x + 1)
        ret = 0; // result
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x = p[i];
        if (x < x0) return 0;
        a = x % m * x % m * ((x + 1) / 2 % m) % m;
        for (var k = x0 + 1; k <= x + 1; k++)
            fac = fac * (k % m) % m;
        ret = ((ret + a) % m + fac - 1) % m;
        x0 = x;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Note that it assumes `p` is a sorted array.

Comment: Good point about p being a sorted array.
I'm not sure that giving a complete code is the best answer format for this kind of question. After all, it's a challenge that Atul Shanbhag was trying to solve on it's own

Comment: @Daniel Sokolov I'm new to CR. I used to give answers in the SO style

Comment: @hindmost: Your answer is fine: it's normal to include model code in answers here at Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a dynamic programming exercise to me.
You should store values of already calculated factorials. Then, you can do n! = (n-1)!*n   and save the time waisted in the for loop.

P.S.

I'm not sure why you use modulo M everywhere in your solution. The problem is asking you to calculate the formula and give a result as modulo M

Comment: The function F(x) = 1*1!+2*2!+...x*x! can be further reduced to ( x*x*(x+1) )/2+(x+1)!-1 and I'm taking modulus by M because x could be 10^18 so trying to reduce it down

Comment: P.S. I do get right output

Comment: @Atul Shanbhag Can you clarify how you get `xx*(x+1)/2+(x+1)!-1` from the `F(x)` definition? I understand that `xx*(x+1)/2` is a sum of [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). But how you get `(x+1)!-1`? I think it should be: `1 + 2*2! + ... + x*x!` which is not the same as `(x+1)!-1`. Isn't it?

Comment: It is the same. Think of x*x! as (x+1-1)*x! which is (x+1)!-x!..Summing them up gives that expression

Comment: @AtulShanbhag, How does it help you with the original problem of having to calculate the factorial for every p[i], though?
If you stored the results for say f(4) globally, you could use that result when calculating f(6)

Comment: i think the problem in that again would be over flow

Comment: You can store the result after calculating the modulo

Comment: But I don't think that will help efficiency? Like I said I have problem in subtasks 2,3,4. This problem got accepted as right answer only those subtasks get TLE.